# How can i use a listview on my home page?

Tags: list, document-library, list-view

I added a list and created some standart listviews. ı am trying to add them to my home page via Edit Page >> Insert >> Web Part but it made come all list. I want to access the listviews.

Answer (score 2):

You have to first add a webpart for a list that you have created. When webpart is added, you have to Edit Web Part properties and select one of the views that you have created:
[image: List View Web Part settings]